# Programming a motor with an RGB

Tags: motor, relay, programming

*Please see the comments section if confused.*
I am trying to turn a motor on and off once per second, and when the motor is on, the RGB turns green. When the motor is off, the RGB is red. Everything is connected to an arduino UNO.I have the motor connected to pins 0 and 1, and to the 5V and GND. The RGB is connected to pins 4, 5, and 6, and the 5V.
I have two codes; one with a bunch of screwing around with a bunch of different loops and everything else I've tried, and one with the simple motor on/off code.

```
void setup ()
{
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT); //IB1
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT); //IA1
////  pinMode(2,OUTPUT); //IB2
////  pinMode(3,OUTPUT); //IA2
//  pinMode(4,OUTPUT); //RGB
//  pinMode(5,OUTPUT); //RGB
//  pinMode(6,OUTPUT); //RGB
//  pinMode(A0,INPUT); //lMotor
////  pinMode(A1,INPUT); //rMotor
//  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop ()
{
  digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(0,LOW);
  delay(1000);

//  int lMotor = analogRead(A0);
//  Serial.write(lMotor);
////  int lMotor = analogRead(A1);
////  Serial.write(lMotor);
//  
//  if (lMotor>10)
//  {
//    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
//    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
//    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
//  }
//  else
//  {
//    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
//    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
//    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
//  }
}
```

And here's this:

```
void setup ()
{
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT); 
}

void loop ()
{
  digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(0,LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

What do I need to do? Should I use a "while" loop? If so, how?
Is my circuit put together properly? I'm using a motor relay switch to turn the motor on/off, but I'm pretty sure it's hooked up right.
Any help is appreciated, even if it doesn't answer all of my questions. 
Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to investigate what "component video" signals should look like. It is too simple to assume you can just drive a pin high and expect the screen to color accordingly.

Comment: @jippie I am not changing anything on screen, I am turning an RGB LED on. (Everything is connected to the arduino via a breadboard.)

Comment: You haven't actually told us what's not working. Is the motor not turning? At the top you say you have the motor connected to pins 0 and 1 and 5 V and ground! How? What's the relay doing? Can you hear the relay clicking? We'll need a schematic or a photo of a sketch. Note that the Arduino pins can't provide enough current to drive a typical little DC motor.

Comment: @transistor The motor turns with the simple code (the second one in my post); my problem is basically I don't know what to do to make the RGB turn on and change colors based on the current state of the motor (on or off). Everything works properly until I add something to the code (because someone, or some site, suggested that's what I should do); by "not working properly" I mean the entire circuit does nothing. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: If my response below doesn't answer the question can you edit the question to clearly show the code that works and the code that doesn't and explain what works - e.g., the motor works but the LEDs don't.

Comment: I forgot to say, the way you've set up the first code example you turn the motor on for a second, then turn in off for a second and then updated the LEDs. The LEDs are only updated when the motor is off so they'll never change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void setup ()
{
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT); //IB1
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT); //IA1
//  pinMode(2,OUTPUT); //IB2
//  pinMode(3,OUTPUT); //IA2
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT); //RGB red
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT); //RGB green
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT); //RGB blue
  boolean motorOn = false;
}

void loop ()
{
  digitalWrite(0,motorOn);
  if(motorOn) {
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);  // red on
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);   // green off
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);   // blue off
  }
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);   // red off
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);  // green on
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);   // blue off
  }
  delay(1000);             // wait
  motorOn = !motorOn;      // toggle the status of the motor.
}
```

The code above has the disadvantage that the on-time is the same as the off-time. We can make the code more flexible and a little more like your original by doing the LED related code in a subroutine:

```
void setup ()
{
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT);   //IB1
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT);   //IA1
//  pinMode(2,OUTPUT); //IB2
//  pinMode(3,OUTPUT); //IA2
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);   //RGB red
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);   //RGB green
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);   //RGB blue
  boolean motorOn = false;
}

void loop ()
{
  motorOn = false;
  digitalWrite(0,motorOn);
  updateLEDs();            // update the LED status
  delay(1000);             // wait
  motorOn = true;          // toggle the status of the motor.
  digitalWrite(0,motorOn);
  updateLEDs();            // update the LED status
  delay(750);              // wait a different time
}

void updateLEDs(){
  // This routine updates the LEDs based on status of motorOn.
  if(motorOn) {
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);  // red on
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);   // green off
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);   // blue off
  }
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);   // red off
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);  // green on
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);   // blue off
  }
}
```